# hive - mismatched input ''output.format.string'' expecting )

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive

I am trying to create a hive table from hive.log (from /tmp//hive.log).

Sample line from log:

> 2015-06-14 06:01:40,206 INFO  [main]: ql.Driver (Driver.java:compile(433)) - Semantic Analysis Completed

Here is the create query and regex in it:

```
 CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE HIVELOG_TEMP(DATE STRING,TIME STRING,LOG_LEVEL STRING,FILE STRING,FUNC STRING,SUB_FUNC STRING,LOG_MSG STRING)
 ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
 WITH SERDEPROPERTIES(
 'input.regex' = '([^\ ]*) ([^\ ]*) ([^\ ]*)  \[([^\ ]*)\]: ([^\ ]*) \(([^\ ]*)\(.*\) - (.*)\n'
'output.format.string' = "%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s %5$s %6$s %7$s" )
LOCATION '/user/hive/warehouse/hive.log';
```

I am getting the following error:

> FAILED: ParseException line 5:0 mismatched input ''output.format.string'' expecting ) near ''([^\ ]*) ([^\ ]*) ([^\ ]*)  [([^\ ]*)]: ([^\ ]*) (([^\ ]*)(.*) - (.*)\n'' in table properties

Tried with other options also, but got the same error always. Couldn't figure out the problem. Any help?

Comment: You need to escape `[]` and `()`

Comment: Try double escaping: `([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) \\[([^ ]*)\\]: ([^ ]*) \\(([^ ]*)\\(.*\\) - (.*)\n`.

Comment: Tried double escaping; with same regex you suggested, but of no use. Go this error again.    mismatched input ''output.format.string'' expecting ) near ''([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) \\[([^ ]*)\\]: ([^ ]*) \\(([^ ]*)\\(.*\\) - (.*)\n'' in table properties

Comment: Solved - It was a silly mistake which took some time to find out. There is a ',' missing after the 'input.regex' parameter.